# Both production and staging server running same cron in Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, cron, scheduled-tasks

I have created an ASP.NET application which is deployed on Azure.

Every time whenever I want to publish it on Azure, I make use of a staging server to deploy and after testing everything on staging, I just swap both of them.

But there is a problem, I have some startup tasks that create some scheduled tasks for cron jobs. So, these task are also copied to production server from staging and cron jobs are run two times one on production and second in staging. But I want them only to run on production not on staging.

How can I prevent this duplicated cron job problem? Please give me some suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way in order to distuinguish staging and production environments.
If I do remember correctly, you could use the Server Management REST Api to get more details about the current deployment. You just need to get the RoleEnvironment.DeploymentId and communicate with the REST Api by providing a valid X509 Certificate.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460806.aspx